# Golang Program leaking memory

Tags: go

I am trying to write a simple program that behaves like find | grep in golang. I have the program all working using goroutines using the following pattern:

goroutine (filech <- each file as found)
goroutine (store files in extension based category <- grepch)

goroutine for each filech file (grepch <- if file contains string)

This all works as expected, but when presented with a large number of files, the memory just keeps growing and growing. I have looked into some of the profiling tools offered by Go, but I couldn't figure out how to find my memory leak. I can say that the memory is being used up mostly by bytes.makeSlice.

Can anyone look at the code below and see what I am doing wrong? Also, I would like to know what is wrong with my code, but I would also like to learn how to debug this on my own in the future, so if you could give detailed profiling instructions for a problem such as this, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var (
    topDir      string
    cProf       bool
    mProf       bool
    cProfFile   *os.File
    mProfFile   *os.File
    fileNames   []string
    fileTypes   []string
    fileLists   map[string][]string
    cMatch      = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:c|h|cc|cpp|c\+\+|hpp)$`)
    javaMatch   = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:java|js)$`)
    goMatch     = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:go)$`)
    buildMatch  = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:gradle|mk|mka)$`)
    buildMatch2 = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*/(?:Makefile[^/\\]*)$`)
    regMatch    = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(?:test|debug)`)
)

func init() {
    fileLists = make(map[string][]string)
}

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&topDir, "d", ".", "The top level directory to process (default is current directory)")
    flag.BoolVar(&cProf, "c", false, "Include if you want to save the CPU profile")
    flag.BoolVar(&mProf, "m", false, "Include if you want to save the MEM profile")
    flag.Parse()

    cProfFunc()

    getFilesChan := make(chan string, 1000)
    grepFilesChan := make(chan string, 100)

    go getFileNamesOverChan(topDir, getFilesChan)

    var fileResult string

    var grepWg sync.WaitGroup
    var categorizeWg sync.WaitGroup

    fileTypes = append(fileTypes, "C", "Java", "Go", "Build", "Uncategorized")

    categorizeWg.Add(1)
    go func(chan string) {
        var grepResult string
        for grepResult = range grepFilesChan {
            if grepResult != "" {
                fmt.Printf("Found file %s with text\n", grepResult)
                var fileType = getFileCategory(grepResult)
                fileLists[fileType] = append(fileLists[fileType], grepResult)
            }
        }
        categorizeWg.Done()
    }(grepFilesChan)

    for fileResult = range getFilesChan {
        if fileResult != "" {
            fileNames = append(fileNames, fileResult)
            grepWg.Add(1)
            go func(file string, ch chan string) {
                fmt.Printf("Grepping file %s\n", file)
                grepOverChan(file, ch)
                grepWg.Done()
            }(fileResult, grepFilesChan)
        }

    }

    grepWg.Wait()
    close(grepFilesChan)
    categorizeWg.Wait()

    printSummary()
    mProfFunc()

    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    defer cProfFile.Close()
}

func cProfFunc() {
    if cProf {
        cProfFile, _ = os.Create("cpu_profile.pprof")
        //handle err
        _ = pprof.StartCPUProfile(cProfFile)
        //handle err
    }

}

func mProfFunc() {
    if mProf {
        mProfFile, _ = os.Create("mem_profile.pprof")
        //handle err
        _ = pprof.WriteHeapProfile(mProfFile)
        //handle err
        defer mProfFile.Close()
    }
}

func printSummary() {
    fmt.Printf("\n\nProcessed %d Files\n\n", len(fileNames))

    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println("Found text in the following files:")

    for _, fType := range fileTypes {
        fmt.Printf("Found text in %d %s Files\n", len(fileLists[fType]), fType)
    }
    /*
        for _, fType := range fileTypes {
            if len(fileLists[fType]) > 0 {
                fmt.Println("")
                fmt.Printf("\t%s Files:\n", fType)
            }

            for _, fileName := range fileLists[fType] {
                fmt.Printf("\t\t%s\n", fileName)
            }
        }
    */
}

func getFileNamesOverChan(directory string, ch chan string) {
    fmt.Printf("Finding files in directory %s\n", directory)
    var err error
    var dirInfo os.FileInfo

    dirInfo, err = os.Lstat(directory)
    if err != nil {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    if !dirInfo.IsDir() {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    recursiveGetFilesOverChan(directory, ch)

    close(ch)
}

func recursiveGetFilesOverChan(dir string, ch chan string) {
    dirFile, _ := os.Open(dir)
    //handle err
    defer dirFile.Close()

    dirFileInfo, _ := dirFile.Readdir(0)
    //handle err

    for _, file := range dirFileInfo {
        filePath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%c%s", dir, os.PathSeparator, file.Name())
        switch mode := file.Mode(); {
        case mode.IsDir():
            //is a directory ... recurse
            recursiveGetFilesOverChan(filePath, ch)
        case mode.IsRegular():
            //is a regular file ... send it if it is not a CVS or GIT file
            if !strings.Contains(filePath, "/CVS/") && !strings.Contains(filePath, "/.git/") {
                fmt.Printf("Found File %s\n", filePath)
                ch <- filePath
            }
        case mode&os.ModeSymlink != 0:
            //is a symbolic link ... skip it
            continue
        case mode&os.ModeNamedPipe != 0:
            //is a Named Pipe ... skip it
            continue
        }
    }
}

func getFileCategory(file string) string {
    var fileType string

    switch {
    case cMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "C"
    case javaMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Java"
    case goMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Go"
    case buildMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Build"
    case buildMatch2.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Build"
    default:
        fileType = "Uncategorized"
    }
    return fileType
}

func grepOverChan(f string, ch chan string) {
    fileBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
    if regMatch.Match(fileBytes) {
        ch <- f
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you measure that your code is leaking memory? Most probably your measurements will be wrong.

Comment: You are aware that you are trying to slurp all the files into memory concurrently? I'm not surprised this consumes huge amounts of memory (and it's not a leak). Also, it seems you are re-inventing [filepath.Walk](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk).

Comment: I am aware that I am sleeping entire files into memory, but I thought that I would only be sleeping 100 files at a time due to the buffer on grepFilesChan. Then I expected the memory to be freed after the respective go routine finishes. And I was reinventing filepath.Walk because I wanted to filter out directories with certain names from being walked and didn't see that functionality in filepath.Walk.

Comment: I am measuring by watching top as my program runs. The memory in use constantly grows and never goes down until the program consumes all memory and crashes. Open to other suggestions to actually pinpoint the problem, but that's not the behavior that I would expect from this program. I'm guessing that the program is not ever GC the byte slices from reading the full files in the go routine that calls grepOverChan. I just can't confirm that and don't know what I'm doing wrong to cause that to happen.

Comment: There is no memory leak here. You're trying concurrently process files with no limit. You attempt to read every single file concurrently, in its entirety, then send those huge blobs to a regex. Once you have any backlog, everything is going to get slower and the issue compounds itself. You need to limit concurrency, and don't read the entire contents of every file at once.

Comment: Thanks JimB. For limiting the concurrency, would you suggest the semaphore channel approach in http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go/? It seems easy enough to add to my program around the grep goroutine. What is another way to read and grep the files without reading the entire contents (keeping in mind that in the real program vs this simple example, I need to grep both text and binary files)?

Comment: @Kris: yes a semaphore is as easy way to limit concurrency. Scanning by lines is simple, but there is no easy way to make a function to "grep" large binary files -- you always have to check if there might be a match between buffered chunks. Think carefully if that is something you actually want to do, since it's really of limited usefulness.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks again. I implemented the semaphore limiting channel this morning and this allowed my process to complete against the large file structure that it needs to run against. The memory use is still high because it still loads in the whole files, but it does grow to a certain point and then tops out (once it hits the limit). I made the limit configurable with a runtime flag. I will include my new code as an answer to this question in case anyone else runs across it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by @JimB to my question, I was able to figure out that this was not a memory leak per say, but a problem of unlimited concurrency. My original code was kicking off a grep for every file as it was encountered without limit.

I was able to resolve this problem by limiting the number of files opened to grep at any one time. Using the example provided by http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go/. In this link, they create a semaphoreChannel that will only accept the limit number of messages. Write a value to this channel before opening a file, and read a value from this channel after finished searching the file. At the end wait for the semaphoreChannel to fill up again.

Here is the working code that corresponds to my broken original code (see `grepConcurrencyLimit` and `semaphoreChan` for the relevant portions):

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var (
    topDir               string
    cProf                bool
    mProf                bool
    cProfFile            *os.File
    mProfFile            *os.File
    fileNames            []string
    fileTypes            []string
    fileLists            map[string][]string
    grepConcurrencyLimit int
    cMatch               = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:c|h|cc|cpp|c\+\+|hpp)$`)
    javaMatch            = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:java|js)$`)
    goMatch              = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:go)$`)
    buildMatch           = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^.*\.(?:gradle|mk|mka)$`)
    buildMatch2          = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*/(?:Makefile[^/\\]*)$`)
    regMatch             = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(?:test|debug)`)
)

func init() {
    fileLists = make(map[string][]string)
}

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&topDir, "d", ".", "The top level directory to process (default is current directory)")
    flag.IntVar(&grepConcurrencyLimit, "l", 50, "The limit of number of files to grep at any one time")
    flag.BoolVar(&cProf, "c", false, "Include if you want to save the CPU profile")
    flag.BoolVar(&mProf, "m", false, "Include if you want to save the MEM profile")
    flag.Parse()

    cProfFunc()

    getFilesChan := make(chan string, 1000)
    grepFilesChan := make(chan string, 100)

    // This channel is to ensure that only grepConcurrencyLimit files are ever grepped at any one time
    semaphoreChan := make(chan bool, grepConcurrencyLimit)

    go getFileNamesOverChan(topDir, getFilesChan)

    var fileResult string

    var grepWg sync.WaitGroup
    var categorizeWg sync.WaitGroup

    fileTypes = append(fileTypes, "C", "Java", "Go", "Build", "Uncategorized")

    categorizeWg.Add(1)
    go func(chan string) {
        var grepResult string
        for grepResult = range grepFilesChan {
            if grepResult != "" {
                fmt.Printf("Found file %s with text\n", grepResult)
                var fileType = getFileCategory(grepResult)
                fileLists[fileType] = append(fileLists[fileType], grepResult)
            }
        }
        categorizeWg.Done()
    }(grepFilesChan)

    for fileResult = range getFilesChan {
        if fileResult != "" {
            fileNames = append(fileNames, fileResult)
            grepWg.Add(1)
            // write a boolean to semaphoreChan to take up one of the concurrency limit spots
            semaphoreChan <- true
            go func(file string, ch chan string) {
                fmt.Printf("Grepping file %s\n", file)
                //run the function to read a boolean from semaphoreChan to release one of the concurrency limit spots
                defer func() { <-semaphoreChan }()
                grepOverChan(file, ch)
                grepWg.Done()
            }(fileResult, grepFilesChan)
        }

    }

    // refill semaphoreChan to capacity to wait until all of the final go routines have completed.
    for i := 0; i < cap(semaphoreChan); i++ {
        semaphoreChan <- true
    }

    grepWg.Wait()
    close(grepFilesChan)
    categorizeWg.Wait()

    printSummary()
    mProfFunc()

    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    defer cProfFile.Close()
}

func cProfFunc() {
    if cProf {
        cProfFile, _ = os.Create("cpu_profile.pprof")
        //handle err
        _ = pprof.StartCPUProfile(cProfFile)
        //handle err
    }

}

func mProfFunc() {
    if mProf {
        mProfFile, _ = os.Create("mem_profile.pprof")
        //handle err
        _ = pprof.WriteHeapProfile(mProfFile)
        //handle err
        defer mProfFile.Close()
    }
}

func printSummary() {
    fmt.Printf("\n\nProcessed %d Files\n\n", len(fileNames))

    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println("Found text in the following files:")

    for _, fType := range fileTypes {
        fmt.Printf("Found text in %d %s Files\n", len(fileLists[fType]), fType)
    }
    /*
        for _, fType := range fileTypes {
            if len(fileLists[fType]) > 0 {
                fmt.Println("")
                fmt.Printf("\t%s Files:\n", fType)
            }

            for _, fileName := range fileLists[fType] {
                fmt.Printf("\t\t%s\n", fileName)
            }
        }
    */
}

func getFileNamesOverChan(directory string, ch chan string) {
    fmt.Printf("Finding files in directory %s\n", directory)
    var err error
    var dirInfo os.FileInfo

    dirInfo, err = os.Lstat(directory)
    if err != nil {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    if !dirInfo.IsDir() {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    recursiveGetFilesOverChan(directory, ch)

    close(ch)
}

func recursiveGetFilesOverChan(dir string, ch chan string) {
    dirFile, _ := os.Open(dir)
    //handle err
    defer dirFile.Close()

    dirFileInfo, _ := dirFile.Readdir(0)
    //handle err

    for _, file := range dirFileInfo {
        filePath := fmt.Sprintf("%s%c%s", dir, os.PathSeparator, file.Name())
        switch mode := file.Mode(); {
        case mode.IsDir():
            //is a directory ... recurse
            recursiveGetFilesOverChan(filePath, ch)
        case mode.IsRegular():
            //is a regular file ... send it if it is not a CVS or GIT file
            if !strings.Contains(filePath, "/CVS/") && !strings.Contains(filePath, "/.git/") {
                fmt.Printf("Found File %s\n", filePath)
                ch <- filePath
            }
        case mode&os.ModeSymlink != 0:
            //is a symbolic link ... skip it
            continue
        case mode&os.ModeNamedPipe != 0:
            //is a Named Pipe ... skip it
            continue
        }
    }
}

func getFileCategory(file string) string {
    var fileType string

    switch {
    case cMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "C"
    case javaMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Java"
    case goMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Go"
    case buildMatch.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Build"
    case buildMatch2.MatchString(file):
        fileType = "Build"
    default:
        fileType = "Uncategorized"
    }
    return fileType
}

func grepOverChan(f string, ch chan string) {
    fileBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
    if regMatch.Match(fileBytes) {
        ch <- f
    }
}
```